# Exect conversion of panda data frame column from numeric to string with proper NaN handling

Tags: python, pandas

Below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'object': ['a', 'b', 'c',np.nan],
                   'numeric': [1, 2, np.nan , 4],
                 })


df['both'] = df['object'] + '__' + df['numeric'].astype(str)
```

After running it `df` looks like:

```
object   numeric   both
a          1             a__1.0
b          2             b__2.0
c          nan          c__nan
nan      4              nan
```

Above in column `both` I need to instead of `NaN` to add nothing and numerics added in `both` column should look as are in `numeric` column (without added `.0` and etc). So,  I want to get instead:

```
object   numeric   both
a          1             a__1
b          2             b__2
c          nan          c__
nan      4              4__
```

Comment: `fillna('')` first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just run an if statement to check if you have nulls or not.

you could use `fillna` but then you'd have mismatched '__' on either side.

```
conditions = [(df['numeric'].isnull()),
             (df['object'].isnull())]

outputs = [df["object"].astype(str) + "__", df["numeric"].astype(str) + "__"]

df['both']  = np.select(conditions,outputs,default= 
             df['object'] + '__' + df['numeric'].astype(str))

print(df)
  object  numeric    both
0      a      1.0  a__1.0
1      b      2.0  b__2.0
2      c      NaN     c__
3    NaN      4.0   4.0__
```

if you're using `pandas 0.24+` then you can take advantage of the `Int64` dtype which handles nan values :

read more [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html)

```
df['numeric'] = df['numeric'].astype('Int64')

df['both']  = np.select(conditions,outputs,default=  
            df['object'] + '__' + df['numeric'].astype(str))
print(df)
  object  numeric  both
0      a        1  a__1
1      b        2  b__2
2      c      NaN   c__
3    NaN        4   4__
```

Comment: But in your example in `both` column the number parts are with `.0`. How to make them look as in original column (no `.0`, etc)?

Comment: Thank you. The last row of the "both" column contains `4.0__`. So it contains `.0`

Comment: Here is complete code that I tested: `import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'object': ['a', 'b', 'c',np.nan],
                   'numeric': [1, 2, np.nan , 4],
                 })

conditions = [(df['numeric'].isnull()),
             (df['object'].isnull())]

outputs = [df["object"].astype(str) + "__", df["numeric"].astype(str) + "__"]

df['numeric'] = df['numeric'].astype('Int64')

df['both']  = np.select(conditions,outputs,default=  
            df['object'] + '__' + df['numeric'].astype(str))
print(df)`

Comment: put `df['numeric'] =  df['numeric'].astype('Int64') ` at the top of the code after your dataframe @vasili111